# How to split a text-block into 2 strings, in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a text-block, with this content:

```
[/+]There is my first text[+/]. There is my second text.

[/+]There is my third text.[+/]
There is my fourth text.

...
```

Now, I want to split it into 2 strings:

1. `$str_1 = "There is my first text.";`
2. ```
   $str_2 = " There is my second text.
   ```

```
[/+]There is my third text.[+/]
```

```
There is my fourth text.

...";
```

---

Could you show me: "How to split a text-block into 2 strings, in PHP?".

Comment: At least try something before you ask question...newbie is not an excuse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode function in php

```
explode($delimiter, "String");
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: There are many ways to make that,

1. explode -2times or 3times 
2. preg_split- $output = preg_split( '/(\[\/\+\]|\[\+\/\])/', "yout string");

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your question but I think you might be looking for this

```
$str = "[/+]There is my first text[+/]. There is my second text.

[/+]There is my third text.[+/]
There is my fourth text.";

preg_match_all('/(\[\/\+])?([\w\s.]+)(\[\+\/])?/',$str,$m);

$str = "";
foreach($m[2] as $k => $v){
  ${"str".$k} = $v;
}

echo $str0."\n";
echo $str1."\n";
echo $str2."\n";
echo $str3."\n";
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/473279)